# Qt Can't figure out what to do with operands error

Tags: qt, syntax-error

So I know it is pretty basic problem but I can't figure out what to do.
Here is my code:

```
 IpResolver::ResolvedInfo IpResolver::resolveIp(const QString &ip)
{
      ResolvedInfo rI;

if (_IpResolver.find(rI.ip) != _IpResolver.end())
    return _IpResolver[ip];

_IpResolver[ip] = QString();
actualResolve(ip);

return rI.country;
}
```

And there are two errors saying:
1. no operator "=" matches these operands, operand types are "IpResolver::ResolvedInfo" and QString 
2.  no suitable user-defined conversion from "QString" to "IpResolver::ResolvedInfo" exists

Comment: can you specify the type of `_IpResolver` or show its declaration

Comment: Your code doesn't make much sense. The `find` call uses `rI` which is default-constructed, and doesn't use `ip`. Please rethink the whole method.

Comment: _IpResolver is private map declared in IpResolver.h: std::map<QString, ResolvedInfo> _IpResolver;

Comment: The errors are pretty clear, you cannot convert different variable types as you think it could be... but as it is.  Check the way you're converting your `_IpResolver[ip]` into `QString`

Comment: It is impossible to answer this question without you providing enough code to compile this fragment, with the only error being the error you report above.

Answer (score 1):

Do you know what is a map? It stores items, accessing them with keys. The syntax is :

```
map[key] = item;
```

When you write

```
_IpResolver[ip] = QString();
```

it is like writing

```
map[key] = key;
```

that does not have much sense, because the map currently stores some `IpResolver::ResolvedInfo` as you defined it and as the compiler recalls to you.